# Drop down refreshes the page something with href

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem here is that when I click the other lang it does not change the drop down to that particular lang, my code was working fine it was changing until the moment I added href to

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var itaImgLink = "http://www.roemheld.de/IT/Data/Images/Address/Italien.gif";
     var engImgLink = "http://www.roemheld.de/IT/Data/Images/Address/Grossbritanien.gif";
  var deuImgLink = "http://www.roemheld.de/IT/Data/Images/Address/Deutschland.gif";
  var fraImgLink = "http://www.roemheld.de/IT/Data/Images/Address/Frankreich.gif";

  var imgBtnSel = $('#imgBtnSel');
  var imgBtnIta = $('#imgBtnIta');
  var imgBtnEng = $('#imgBtnEng');
  var imgBtnDeu = $('#imgBtnDeu');
  var imgBtnFra = $('#imgBtnFra');

  var imgNavSel = $('#imgNavSel');
  var imgNavIta = $('#imgNavIta');
  var imgNavEng = $('#imgNavEng');
  var imgNavDeu = $('#imgNavDeu');
  var imgNavFra = $('#imgNavFra');

  var spanNavSel = $('#lanNavSel');
  var spanBtnSel = $('#lanBtnSel');

  imgBtnSel.attr("src",itaImgLink);
  imgBtnIta.attr("src",itaImgLink);
  imgBtnEng.attr("src",engImgLink);
  imgBtnDeu.attr("src",deuImgLink);
  imgBtnFra.attr("src",fraImgLink);

  imgNavSel.attr("src",itaImgLink);
  imgNavIta.attr("src",itaImgLink);
  imgNavEng.attr("src",engImgLink);
  imgNavDeu.attr("src",deuImgLink);
  imgNavFra.attr("src",fraImgLink);
    
    
      var engLink    = "{{url('language/en')}}";
      var deuLink    = "{{url('language/de')}}";
      var fraLink    = "{{url('language/fr')}}";
      var itaLink    = "{{url('language/it')}}";
  


     
      var linkNavIta = $('#navIta');
      var linkNavEng = $('#navEng');
      var linkNavDeu = $('#navDeu');
      var linkNavFra = $('#navFra');
   

      var linkNavSel = $('#linkNavSel');

  
    $( ".language" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
      var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

      if(currentId == "navIta") {
        imgNavSel.attr("src",itaImgLink);
        spanNavSel.text("IT");

        linkNavSel.attr("href",itaLink);
      } else if (currentId == "navEng") {
        imgNavSel.attr("src",engImgLink);
        spanNavSel.text("EN");
         linkNavSel.attr("href",engLink);
      }
         else if (currentId == "navDeu") {
        imgNavSel.attr("src",deuImgLink);
        spanNavSel.text("DE");
         linkNavSel.attr("href",deuLink);
      } else if (currentId == "navFra") {
        imgNavSel.attr("src",fraImgLink);
        spanNavSel.text("FR");
         linkNavSel.attr("href",fraLink);
      } 



      
    });
});
```

```css
.icon-small
{
    height:18px;
    margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.icon-medium
{
    height:22px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<body>


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img id="imgNavSel" src="" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail icon-small">  <span id="lanNavSel">ITA</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a id="navIta" href="#" class="language"> <img id="imgNavIta" src="" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail icon-small">  <span id="lanNavIta">Italiano</span></a></li>
                        <li><a id="navDeu" href="#" class="language"> <img id="imgNavDeu" src="" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail icon-small">  <span id="lanNavDeu">Deutsch</span></a></li>
               <li><a id="navFra" href="#" class="language"><img id="imgNavFra" src="" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail icon-small">  <span id="lanNavFra">Francais</span></a></li>
               <li><a id="navEng" href="#" class="language"><img id="imgNavEng" src="" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail icon-small">  <span id="lanNavEng">English</span></a></li>
                 </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
     
    
</body>
```

Here it works as you can see, since the  links that I am using are from local host and know it cannot show, but when I try the links appear on each language and I can click the language that I want, it changes that but as soon as I click that it refreshes the page and It stays the first one the italian again  it does not change to the other that I selected, I am using Laravel here, I think I has something to do with href link Can someone help me.

Comment: convert `href="#"` to `href="javascript:void(0);"` and try

Answer (score 0):

In your click event use `preventDefault` to over-ride the value you've set to the href attribute :

```
 $( ".language" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        .
        . // rest of your code
  }
```

Comment: This prevents the link, and then the link its not working, it is not changing my language

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is cancel the click event with JavaScript to prevent the default action from happening. So when someone clicks the link with JavaScript enabled, the click event is cancelled as you are returning false and prevents the browser from refreshing.

You have to add this code in your jQuery snippet:

```
$('a').click(function() {

    //you can write something else here if you want

    return false; // cancel the event
});
```